# Why isn't validations working with `embeds_one`?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Why isn't validations working with `embeds_one`?

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :bar, :cascade_callbacks => true
end

class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :foo

  field :test, :type => String
  field :year, :type => Integer, :default => Time.now.utc.year
  field :month, :type => Integer, :default => Time.now.utc.month
  field :day, :type => Integer, :default => Time.now.utc.day

  # validates :year, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true, :scope => [:month, :day]
  # validates :day, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:month,:year] }
  validates_uniqueness_of :year, :scope => :day
end

Foo.create(:bar => { :test => 'asdf' }) # created document
Foo.create(:bar => { :test => 'asdf' }) # created document, no validation thrown!
```

Why is Foo being created multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to `validates_uniqueness_of`, [Mongoid's document](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html) says:

> Validate that an attribute is unique. Note that for embedded documents, this will only check that the field is unique within the context of the parent document, not the entire database.

In your case, two distinct documents are created in the example.  Therefore, the behavior is correct in Mongoid.